# Regex for phone number masking in Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to mask a phone number

```
90 511 619 11 21
```

like this

```
5**6**1*2*
```

first I'm checking if it contains 90 (country code) and removing it

```
if (number.length() > 2 && number.substring(0,2).contains("90")){
            number = number.replaceAll(number.substring(0,2), "");
        }
```

then I'm removing all the spaces but I'm stuck at the regex part.

```
number = number.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "*");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can solve this problem without using any capture groups:

```
String input = "533 619 11 21";
input = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\d", "*").replaceAll(" ", "");
System.out.println(input);

5**6**1*2*
```

The replacement logic here is that any single digit which is immediately preceded by a digit gets replaced with asterisk.  This of course spares the first digit.

Note that I assume that you already have some means to remove the country code.

### Demo

Comment: (?<=\\d)\\d+ is ok too

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks...I missed that requirement.

Answer (score 3):

`\d(?<=\d{2})`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/su71C9/3/)

For your code, replace the space after *:

`number = number.replaceAll("\\d(?<=\\d{2})", "*").replaceAll(" ", "");`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it may work for you:

```
^(?:90 *)?(\d)\d{2} *(\d)\d{2} *(\d)\d *(\d)\d$
```

Replace by this:

```
$1**$2**$3*$4*
```

Explanation:

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oby9F8/7)

Sample Java Source ( [run here](https://ideone.com/MH0sRA) ):

```
final String regex = "^(?:90 *)?(\\d)\\d{2} *(\\d)\\d{2} *(\\d)\\d *(\\d)\\d$";
final String string = "90 533 619 11 21";
final String subst = "$1**$2**$3*$4*";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

final String result = matcher.replaceFirst(subst);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex on the string with the 90 already removed:

```
(?<! |^)\d
```

And replace with `*`. This produces `5** 6** 1* 2*`

This looks behind and asserts that there is no space or the start of the string, then it matches a digit.

Then, you can just replace all the spaces with empty strings to get `5**6**1*2*`.